# Request forwarding based on cookie

Tags: apache

For testing purpose, I would like to redirect a request based on a cookie in it. If the cookie is not present the request will be redirect to a default url.

```
<VirtualHost _default_:10000 _default_:20000>
serverName https://www3.mywebsite.com

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} bananaCookie=([^;]+)[NC]
RewriteRule ^banana^$ https://server2.com:30361/banana [L,R=301]

ProxyPass /banana https://server1.com:10300/banana
ProxyPassReverse /banana https://server1.com:10300/banana
<virtualHost>
```

When the user wants to access to url path /banana, in case there is a cookie with value banana in the request, apache should redirect it to https://server2.com:30361/banana, otherwise the request should be redirected to https://server1.com:10300/banana.
The config currently doesn't work. Requests are continuously redirected to the default, whenever a cookie value is set or no.